# sem_close vs sem_unlink when process terminates

Tags: semaphore

I have multiple processes communicating using a semaphore.

```
sem_open("\name",O_CREATE,S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG,10);
```

I have 2 questions w.r.t following:

1. Now, when one process dies suddenly without calling sem_close or sem_unlink. What happens to the remaining processes ?
2. If sem_close() is called, however sem_unlink() is not called for 1 process. All the other processes, call sem_close() and sem_unlink(). Does the semaphore still exists, after all the processes exit ?

Comment: **Related**: [When to call sem_unlink()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15164484/183120)

Answer (score 9):

In answer to your questions:

1. when a process dies, voluntarily or unvoluntarily, the sem_close operation occurs automatically.
2. No, the semaphore does not exist if all processes have exited which had the semaphore opened and at least one process has called sem_unlink.

**To expand a bit:** 
sem_unlink removes the named semaphore, and will destruct the semaphore once its reference count is 0. That is after all process that opened it have called sem_close or have exited.

**References:** Book - Unix Networking Programming-Interprocess Communication by W.Richard Stevens, vol 2, ch10

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but nevertheless I find this information missing in the other answer:

- `sem_close` is associated with the semaphore and its count

  - Semaphore's reference count would be decremented when called
  - Even when count drops to zero semaphore is still kept alive
  - Another process can `sem_open` with same *name*, restoring the count back to `1` (or greater with subsequent `sem_open`s)
- `sem_unlink` is associated with a semaphore's *name*

  - Name is no longer *taken* when called; name is relinquished
  - Semaphores still open (i.e. without `sem_close` calls) are kept alive until ref. count drops to zero
  - When count drops to zero an unlinked semaphore is destroyed
  - If a process `sem_open`s with the same, now-unliked name, it'd get a completely *new* (different) semaphore

Though a semaphore associated with a name is `sem_close`d, the semaphore lives and name stays taken until it's `sem_unlink`ed.